# Random solution In Yices solver

Tags: c, solver, smt

I want to use the [Yices SMT solver](http://yices.csl.sri.com/index.shtml) in a c program to solves the expression `x > 100` and get a solution for `x`. here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"yices_c.h"

int main() {
  yices_context ctx = yices_mk_context();
  char int_ty_name[] = "int";
  yices_type int_ty = yices_mk_type(ctx, int_ty_name);
  char vname[] = "x";
  yices_expr e1 = yices_mk_num(ctx,100);
  yices_var_decl v = yices_mk_var_decl(ctx,vname,int_ty);
  yices_expr e2 = yices_mk_var_from_decl(ctx,v);
  yices_expr eq1 = yices_mk_lt(ctx, e1, e2);
  yices_assert(ctx, eq1);
  yices_dump_context(ctx);
  switch(yices_check(ctx)) {
  case l_true:
    printf("satisfiable\n");
    yices_model m = yices_get_model(ctx);
    long i;
    yices_get_int_value(m,v,&i);
    printf("e2 = %d\n", i);
    yices_display_model(m);
    break;  
  case l_false:
    printf("unsatisfiable\n");
    break;
  case l_undef:
    printf("unknown\n");
    break;
  }
  yices_del_context(ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

This program always results `x =101`. the `101` is only one of possible results for this expression. I want the solver choose a random result from the all possible results ( a random integer from 101 to MAX_INT).

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `yices_find_weighted_model(ctx, 1)` instead of `yices_check(ctx)`.

If you have no weighted constraints, `yices_find_weighted_model(ctx, 0)` should be semantically equivalent to `yices_check(ctx)`.
But the second parameter of `yices_find_weighted_model`, called `random`, allows you to use random search instead of the default decision procedure if you set it to a non-zero value.  Check the [documentation](http://yices.csl.sri.com/capi.shtml#ga27).

Comment: If so, it seems that for your constraints, random search turns out not to be very random.  I don't think there's much you can do; asking an SMT solver to provide all possible models so that you can choose one at random is rather too much.

Comment: i dont want all possible models. i want a model but randomly selected. for example in run number 1 of program i see `x = 1000`, in run number2 `x= 201`, in run number 3 `x = 234234`, and ...

Comment: Yes, I understand, that's more or less what `random` was supposed to be doing.  A pity it doesn't work in your case.  If you know that there are many solutions, you could select at random an interval [a, b) where you want the solution to be, then try restricting with an extra constraint `a <= x < b`.  Repeat, if you were unlucky and no solution was found.

Answer (score 0):

you will have a non-random result first.
then you can add a random constraint (`X>nonRandomResult+delta` or `X<nonRandomResult-delta`) with a random delta.

as long as that cannot be solved, you will have to change the constraint with a new delta that has half of its previous value.
as soon as it has a solution, that solution will most likely be as random as that delta.